# Why does boost::scoped_ptr not work in inheritance scenario?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, polymorphism

When using boost::scoped_ptr to hold a reference, the destructor of the derived object is not called. It does when using boost::shared_ptr.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() { cout << "Base constructor" << endl ; }
    ~Base() { cout << "Base destructor" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base() { cout << "Derived constructor" << endl; }
    ~Derived() { cout << "Derived destructor" << endl; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<Base> pb;  // replacing by shared_ptr does call Derived destructor
    pb.reset(new Derived());
    cout << "Program ends here" << endl;
}
```

Can you explain this? Is there a "golden rule" not to use scoped_ptr for polymorphic member variables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason why it works for [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) is because it implements a special constructor and a [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#reset) method that look like this:

```
template<class T>
class shared_ptr
{
public:
    // ...
    // Note use of template
    template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y * p);
    // ....
    // Note use of template
    template<class Y> void reset(Y * p);
    // ....
};
```

When this constructor or `reset()` is called, `shared_ptr` "remembers" the original type `Y` so that when the reference count goes to zero, it will call `delete` properly. (Of course `p` must be convertible to `T`.) [This is explicitly stated in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors):

> [This constructor has been changed to a template in order to remember
>   the actual pointer type passed. The destructor will call delete with
>   the same pointer, complete with its original type, even when T does
>   not have a virtual destructor, or is void. ...]

The [`scoped_ptr` constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm#constructors) and [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm#reset) look like this:

```
template<class T>
class scoped_ptr : noncopyable
{
public:
    // ...
    explicit scoped_ptr(T * p = 0);
    // ...
    void reset(T * p = 0);
};
```

So there's no way for `scoped_ptr` to "remember" what the original type was. And when it comes time to `delete` the pointer, [it essentially does this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm#destructor):

```
delete this->get();
```

And [`scoped_ptr<T>::get()` returns a `T*`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm#get). So if `scoped_ptr` points to something that's not a `T` but actually a subclass of `T`, you need to implement a `virtual` destructor:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { cout << "Base constructor" << endl ; }
    virtual ~Base() { cout << "Base destructor" << endl; }
};
```

So why doesn't `scoped_ptr` implement a special constructor for this situation like `shared_ptr` does? Because ["scoped_ptr template is a simple solution for simple needs"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm). `shared_ptr` does a lot of bookkeeping to implement its extensive functionality. Note that [`intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) also doesn't "remember" the original type of the pointer since it's meant to be as lightweight as possible (one pointer).

Comment: Your additional information on the "why" makes this an excellent answer. It provides exactly the information I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Unlike `shared_ptr<>`, `scoped_ptr<>` does not "remember" the exact type you pass to its constructor. The http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm[synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) tells:

```
template<class T> class scoped_ptr : noncopyable {

public:
 typedef T element_type;

 explicit scoped_ptr(T * p = 0); // never throws
 ~scoped_ptr(); // never throws

 void reset(T * p = 0); // never throws

 T & operator*() const; // never throws
 T * operator->() const; // never throws
 T * get() const; // never throws

 operator unspecified-bool-type() const; // never throws

 void swap(scoped_ptr & b); // never throws
```

};

I.e. it can't know what exactly you pass, it only knows `T`, which is `Base` in your case. In order to enable correct deletion, you either need to use `shared_ptr<Base>` if that would fit your design, or you must have your `Base` have a virtual destructor

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { cout << "Base constructor" << endl ; }
    virtual ~Base() { cout << "Base destructor" << endl; }
};
```

As a rule of thumb (see also Meyers):

> **Make base-class destructors virtual if you want to delete through the base-class polymorphically.**

Unlike `scoped_ptr<>`, `shared_ptr<>` [explicitly remembers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) the pointer type you pass to the constructor:

```
...
template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y> const & r);
...
```

and the doc says

> This constructor has been changed to a template in order to remember the actual pointer type passed. The destructor will call delete with the same pointer, complete with its original type, even when T does not have a virtual destructor, or is void.

This is made possible by mixing a runtime- with static-polymorphism.

Comment: How could I forget making the destructor virtual. Thanks for explaining why it works with shared_ptr.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a virtual destructor in order for a derived class destructor to be called through a pointer to its base class.